# How to set timeout for task using ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice

Is it possible to timeout a task when using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`? I cannot change the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`  to `ThreadPoolExecutor` or to `ExecutorService`.

Comment: Use `Future.get(long, TimeUnit)`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After submitting a `Callable` to your `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` you should get a `Future`. And on this `Future`, you can call the `get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` function with a `TimeUnit`, which is the timeout, the maximum time the program will wait until either the future delivers or moves on, by throwing a `TimeoutException`.

ie (unconfirmed pseudocode)

```
Future myFuture = threadPoolTaskExecutor.submit(myCallable);
try {
    myResult = myFuture.get(5l,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
} catch(TimeoutException e) {
    // Timeout-Related stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer my below Git hub link for TimeOutThreadPoolTaskExecutor

https://github.com/vivek-gupta-21563/timeoutthreadpool

you can execute or submit a task with preferred time out parameters

```
execute(() -> System.out.println("Task to execute"), 2, TimeUnit.Minute);

submit(() -> System.out.println("Task to execute"), 2, TimeUnit.Minute);
```